Sales Order is being approved despite its Pending Approval status (Approve Sales Order page)
As the title suggests, I am facing with an issue where the Sales Orders are getting approved despite being in an approval workflow.
We have a multi-level approval workflow designed for the Sales Orders. We wish that the orders are approved only via this approval workflow. However, if the User uses the 'Approve Sales Order' page (picture attached below), the Sales Order ignores the approval workflow and directly gets approved.
The business, however, requires this 'Approve Sales Order' page so as to bulk approve the orders.
Is this normal? How can we avoid this from happening?


Confusing situation. You have a page which exists for approving orders, and you said the business needs to use this page to approve orders. But when a user does that, you think that's wrong? Either you need the page and expect it to work, or you don't want users to use it. Sounds like you're trying to have your cake and eat it too. Please update the question if I am misunderstanding what you want to change about this.
